# Adding component in NextJs fails the Hydration

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have this component called Tip, in components/tip.js:

```js
export default function Tip({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-mainblue bg-opacity-50 max-w-4xl border-border border-l-8 rounded p-3">
      <h1 className=" text-link font-bold py-2">TIP</h1>
      <p>{children}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I add this Component in pages/installations.js like this:

```js
<Tip>Hello</Tip>
```

When refreshing the page, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkXgP.jpg).

And the DevTools console shows 8 errors:

1. Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching `<div>` in `<p>`
2. Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
3. Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in `<div>`.
4. Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<h1>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<p>`.
5. Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<p>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<p>`.
6. Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<div>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<p>`.
7. Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
8. Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Comment: can you create a codesandbox example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/eager-albattani-hh53kr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark the styling doesnt apply, but two of the errors here you go @mocherfaoui

Comment: to make that error go change the `<p>` that is wrapping `Tip` in `App` with `<div>`. this DOM nesting issues can cause hydration errors in next.js